NullPointerException when I invoke method from @Schedule of @Startup @Singleton bean
When I try to invoke method of @ViewScoped Bean from @Startup @Singleton bean I always have an error NullPointerException. I use @Schedule annotation method to call @ViewScoped bean method, why it happens?
My TimeBean:
package lv.vda.luis_web.messager.boundary;

import javax.ejb.AccessTimeout;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class TimerBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private TestBean testBean;


    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/20", info = "")
    @AccessTimeout(value = 50000)
    private void timer() {

        testBean.test();

    }
}

My TestBean:
package lv.vda.luis_web.messager.boundary;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;


@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {


    public void test() {

        System.out.println("Checking is ok");

    }

}

Error log:

14:46:40,008 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.timer] (EJB default - 3) WFLYEJB0020: Error invoking timeout for timer: [id=90f8d796-c627-4e49-99a1-51af55c10c94 timedObjectId=luis_web.luis_web.TimerBean auto-timer?:true persistent?:true timerService=org.jboss.as.ejb3.timerservice.TimerServiceImpl@6e86bb33 previousRun=Thu Sep 12 14:36:00 EEST 2024 initialExpiration=null intervalDuration(in milli sec)=0 nextExpiration=Thu Sep 12 14:47:00 EEST 2024 timerState=IN_TIMEOUT info=] ScheduleExpression [second=/20;minute=;hour=;dayOfMonth=;month=;dayOfWeek=;year=*;timezoneID=null;start=null;end=null]: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException


@ViewScoped must be linked to the view. View is something displaying to the user. Usually a content generated from specific .xhtml.
In this case there is no view, as it is a deep backend bean executed by schedule. So no view, no view scope, no view scoped bean.
This is correct behavior.
Probably you want to create a common bean in application, dependant or request scope and inject it into your scheduled bean, as well as into the view scoped bean.
So this common bean will have all the common logic, needed for both backend and front-end.
